# Using multiple, possibly embedded CASE conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am finding how many players of particular Ratings are on teams with various winning percentages. I want to be able to do this query but over multiple years, not just one year. My current query is below.

```
SELECT ROUND(Wins, 1) AS 'Winning Percentage',
SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= 2 and Rating < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rating1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= 5 and Rating < 7 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS Rating2,
SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= 7 and Rating < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rating3 
FROM #temp_table
GROUP BY ROUND(Wins, 1)
ORDER BY ROUND(Wins, 1)
```

Expected result is below.

```
Win %    Rating1 Rating 2 Rating 3
0-25%    3       4        2
25%-100% 4       2        1
```

In #temp_table, I have a WHERE clause for years. I want to be able to do the code above, but across multiple years. #temp_table currently has a @Year variable that I am manually having to enter to generate each #temp_table.

```
My #temp_table is shown below.

Player Rating Year Win % 
Bonds  10     2014  25%
Smith  2      2011  42%
Bryant 5      2013  33%
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results will greatly help us help you.

Comment: `group by year, ROUND(Wins, 1)` maybe?

Comment: So, for that sampel data, what result are you after?

Comment: I am after the result in my post. It is specifically under the 'Expected result is below.' portion of my post.

Comment: @forpas, good suggestion, however I guess one thing to point out is, I haven't been generating #temp_tables for every single year. Rather I am creating #temp_tables for 5 year subsets (2010-2015, 2015-2020, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `case` that will create two groups - `0-25%` and `25%-100%`. Then `group by` this expression. You can add `year` to the query as you mentioned.

```
SELECT case when Wins < 25 then '0-25%'
            when Wins between 25 and 100 then '25%-100%' end  AS 'Winning Percentage',
    year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= 2 and Rating < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rating1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= 5 and Rating < 7 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS Rating2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= 7 and Rating < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rating3 
FROM #temp_table
GROUP BY case when Wins < 25 then '0-25%'
            when Wins between 25 and 100 then '25%-100%' end,
            year
```